# How to achieve interactive PDF in iPhone/iPad programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, pdf

I want to build one iOS application where PDF contains textfields, editable fields etc. Is there any way to develop iOS application, where User can edit textfields and value would be saved to the PDF document locally.

Comment: yes this possible, as most things are. How __you__ implement it is a different story. The fact that you are unaware of it's nature, may mean this is quite an undertaking for you. This is a code heavy process you want to achieve and doubt anyone here will take their time to code everything __for__ you as opposed to helping you when you get stuck on a specific point. I would suggest looking into 3rd party libraries, frameworks or projects. Look into at github there are tons of good starting points there

Comment: So, you essentially want to create a PDF viewer with the capability to handle smart PDFs. As it has been stated in another comment, this is quite a bit beyond a weekend project, even with libraries, and it does require understanding of PDF. It might be more efficient to look out for a decent PDF viewer, and request the users to use that one.

Comment: Hi Guys, I completely agree with your points, it isnt a weekend project at all. It has to be customized in such way that interactive PDF's would be achieved. Could you please let me know any of starting point from where I can carry forward? Any library?